# Show/hide div with javascript

Tags: javascript, visibility

I have a menu which should show the sub-elements organised in a div when clicked.

I provide below the structure of the html

```js
function showOrHide() {
  if (window.innerWidth < 800) {

    var div = document.getElementById("links");
    if (div.style.display == "block") {
      div.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      div.style.display = "block";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<li>
  <div id="image" onclick="showOrHide()">
    <span>Test1</span>
  </div>
  <div id="links">
    <span>Test2</span>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <div id="image" onclick=" showOrHide()">
    <span>Test3</span>
  </div>
  <div id="links">
    <span>Test4</span>
  </div>
</li>
```

I would like the div `id="links"` to be shown or hidden when I click on div `id="image"`. I have the following javascript.

The problem that I face is that onclick javascript is showing all the divs `id=links` in the menu and I would like only the div links next to the div image to be shown. Example when I click on `Test1` only `Test2` should be shown.

Answer (score 2):

Element IDs should be unique within the entire document.

You must try creating unique id per div.

```js
function showOrHide(rowNum) 
{ if (window.innerWidth < 800) { 

    var div = document.getElementById("links_"+ rowNum);
    if (div.style.display == "block") 
    {
        div.style.display = "none";
    }
    else 
    {
        div.style.display = "block";
    }
}
}
```

```html
<li>
<div id="image_1" onclick="showOrHide(1)">
<span>Test1
</span></div>
<div id="links_1">
<span >Test2</span>
</div></li>
<li>
<div id="image_2" onclick=" showOrHide(2)">
<span>Test3
</span></div>
<div id="links_2">
<span >Test4</span>
</div></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change id and structure accordingly.

```
<li>
   <div id="image_1" onclick="showOrHide(1)">
      <span>Test1
      </span>
   </div>
   <div id="links_1">
      <span >Test2</span>
   </div>
</li>
<li>
   <div id="image_2" onclick=" showOrHide(2)">
      <span>Test3
      </span>
   </div>
   <div id="links_2">
      <span >Test4</span>
   </div>
</li>
```

JavaScript:

```
function showOrHide(rowNumber) 
{ if (window.innerWidth < 800) { 

    var div = document.getElementById("links_"+ rowNumber);
    if (div.style.display == "block") 
    {
        div.style.display = "none";
    }
    else 
    {
        div.style.display = "block";
    }
                               }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue here is that an element's `id` must be unique to that element. Other elements cannot have the same `id`. Instead, you can pass through the element into your `showOrHide()` method using `this`, and then get the next element using [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling). This will work provided your HTML structure is consistent:

```js
function showOrHide(elem) {
  if (window.innerWidth < 800) {
    const div = elem.nextElementSibling;
    if (!div.style.display || div.style.display == "block") {
      div.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      div.style.display = "block";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<li>
  <div id="image" onclick="showOrHide(this)">
    <span>Test1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="links">
    <span>Test2</span>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <div id="image" onclick=" showOrHide(this)">
    <span>Test3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="links">
    <span>Test4</span>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just provide a parameter to your `showOrHide` function which will be the selector for your div and do the toggling to that selector. See the implementation below

```
<li>
    <div id="image" onclick="showOrHide('#links_1')">
        <span>Test1</span>
    </div>
    <div id="links_1">
        <span >Test2</span>
    </div> 
</li>
<li>
    <div id="image" onclick=" showOrHide('#links_2')">
        <span>Test3</span>
    </div>
    <div id="links_2">
        <span >Test4</span>
    </div>
</li>
```

And the JS:

```
function showOrHide(divSelector) 
{ 
    var div = document.querySelector(divSelector);
    if (div.style.display == "none") 
    {
        div.style.display = "block";
    }
    else 
    {
        div.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("links");
Array.from(elems).forEach(v => v.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('links')[0].classList.toggle('hidden');
}));
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <div class="links">
    <span>Test1 </span>
  </div>
  <div class="links">
    <span>Test2</span>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class="links">
    <span>Test3
</span></div>
  <div class="links">
    <span>Test4</span>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the same id lots of time on same HTML. Id attribute is unique, but you can use class.
You can use this code maybe it will help you.

```
<li>
<div class="image" onclick="showOrHide(this)">
<span>Test1
</span></div>
<div class="links">
<span >Test2</span>
</div></li>
<li>
<div class="image" onclick=" showOrHide(this)">
<span>Test3
</span></div>
<div class="links">
<span >Test4</span>
</div></li>

function showOrHide(element) {
    if (window.innerWidth < 800) {

        var div = element.closet(".links");
        if (div.style.display == "block") {
            div.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            div.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
```